# How to change the 'default shell' in Bitvise WinSSHD server

Tags: windows, ssh

Hi I have been using WinSSHD and it works pretty good.

How can I change the default shell from **'cmd.exe' -> 'powershell.exe'**

I played around the settings and couldn't find how. Highly appreciate answers! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the control panel's server tab click `Edit advanced settings`. Go to `Access control` in the tree and find and select the group/account you want to edit. Click the `edit` button. If you're editing an account and not group, there is a tick that says `Use group default terminal shell`. In both cases there is a `Terminal shell` field, which you have to set. I just tried it and it works. Some settings there take a windows restart to work. No obvious reason why, but they do.

Comment: To use Cygwin Bash, I picked "bash" as the shell type but selected *C:\cygwin\Cygwin.bat* as the "Bash executable path"; the *C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe* executable didn't work (e.g. running `ls` failed with `command not found`).

Comment: Did you find any solution to that?